# How to grant cross-acount permissions in AWS for a domain hosted in Route53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-iam

I have an old aws account with one hosted external domain. I have a new aws account, and I should manage the domain as a user of the new domain via cli/Terrafrom. How to setup suitable cross-account permissions?

There are a lot of documentation (e.g. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html ), I've tried a lot of ways, but no luck so far.

Comment: Cross account access is the correct way to do things. Domain and Route53 are the services the role needs permissions for, I'd give admin permissions to start with as a test then refine once it's working. Try the tutorial again. [One](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_common-scenarios_aws-accounts.html)[Two](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html).

Comment: Or... just migrate the domain to the new account?